# what is the name of this yellow tape around high frequency transformer?

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, identification, high-frequency

[[image: high frequency transformer[1]]

what is the name of that tape? , what it is the purpose of it?, can I buy it?
And if not, what is the alternative?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's an insulating, flame retardent polyester tape normally used within the layers of transformers to enhance the breakdown voltage capability between primary and secondary.

[image]

3M describe it as: -

> Yellow polyester film tape with an acrylic adhesive. This tape is
>   suited to coil wrapping, wire harnesses, fractional horsepower motors
>   any many more uses. Flame retardant to UL 510.

[3M link](http://www.selfadhesive.co.uk/3m-trade-polyester-insulation-tape-1350-yellow-6mm.html?gclid=Cj0KEQjwuJu9BRDP_-HN9eXs1_UBEiQAlfW39sy0TWVPY-Wx8ORCCoK43EMrI3IMsTwnJzSYWgR_kFAaAgRM8P8HAQ)

Comment: In looking for that 1350 tape I find that google shows lots of links in the UK and Australia, but not in the US so much. Also, I have been using Kapton tape for transformers myself, lately, because I'm learning to like it so much (having used it with my 3D printers now for quite some time.) It certainly handles heat MUCH better than the yellow PET stuff without failures I see in that yellow tape there.

Comment: @wallyk - I rejected your edit because of the extra link you added and the correction to the quote. This may sound harsh but a quote is a quote no matter how illiterate it was in saying "any" instead of "and". Sorry dude, but if you just wish to correct my crappy spelling and tenuous use of "describe" instead of "describes" please go ahead.